# Узнать координаты первого черного пикселя на Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

Вceм привет.

Нужно найти первый черный пиксель в `Bitmap`. Как это делается? Я находил способы получения массива `byte`, допустим, так можно найти сам пиксель, но как взять его координаты?

Comment: L - ширина изображения. N - индекс пикселя в массиве. `y = (int) N / L; x = N % L;`

Comment: @rjhdby зачем `N` приводить к `int`? Индекс в массиве, надо полагать, и так int-овый будет.

Comment: @Regent для наглядности

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поробуйте такой вариант

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
for(x=0; x<bitmap.getWidth();x++){
    for(y=0; y<bitmap.getHeight(); y++){
         int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);
         int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
         int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
         int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);

         //далее нужно сравнить значение redValue, blueValue, greenValue с черным цветом.
    }
}
```

Comment: Этот код скорее академический, потому что функции `getPixel`/`setPixel` безумно медленные.

Comment: а как тогда сделать без использования этого метода? сам буду рад узнать ответ

Comment: Работать с голым массивом, возвращаемым `getPixels`, например.